# how to automatically include the contents as I write the document

Tags: sectioning

I write a document without writing myself the Contents. I just put the command:

```
\tableofcontents
```

and what I write after the command:

```
\begin document
```

is automatically added in the Contents. However , when I have a subsubsection the Latex doesn't include it in the Contents. It is like it doesn't recognize it.

For example I have this file:

```
\documentclass[12pt, fleqn]{report}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \graphicspath{{images/}}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{caption}

 \usepackage{ragged2e}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{afterpage}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{mathptmx}
 \usepackage{anyfontsize}
 \usepackage{t1enc}

 \usepackage{titlesec}

 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\chapter{A}
\section{B}
\subsection{C}
\subsubsection{D}
```

Everything until `\subsection{C}` is included. After I write in the document the`\subsubsection{D}` , then it doesn't appear in the Table of Contents. Any idea why this is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: add `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` to your preamble. Maybe you have to vary the umber to 2 or 4 as you please. I haven't tested it, as your MWE ist not complete.

Comment: Perfect that worked! Thank you guys for the immediate response!